# Capitalize with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, capitalize

I am doing data cleaning with dplyr.
One of the things I want to do is to capitalize values in certain columns.

```
    data$surname
    john
    Mary
    John
    mary
    ...
```

I suppose I have to use the **mutate** function of dplyr with something like this

```
    titleCase <- function(x) {
    + s <- strsplit(as.character(x), " ")[[1]]
    + paste(toupper(substring(s, 1, 1)), substring(s, 2),
    + sep = "", collapse = " ")
    + }
```

But how to combine both? I get all kinds of errors or truncated data frames

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("(.)", "\\U\\1", data$surname, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "John" "Mary" "John" "Mary"
```

Implementing in the `dplyr` workflow

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     mutate(surname = sub("(.)", "\\U\\1", surname, perl=TRUE))
```

If we need to do this on multiple columns

```
data %>%
     mutate_each(funs(sub("(.)", "\\U\\1", ., perl=TRUE)))
```

---

Just to check

```
res <- data1 %>%  
          mutate(surname = sub("(.)", "\\U\\1", surname, perl=TRUE))
sum(grepl("[A-Z]", substr(res$surname, 1,1)))
#[1] 500000
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(surname=c("john", "Mary", "John", "mary"), 
firstname = c("abe", "Jacob", "george", "jen"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

data1 <-  data.frame(surname = sample(c("john", "Mary", "John", "mary"), 
    500000, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun, It works on a reasonably sized data frame, I've checked. But no effect, and no error displayed either, on my  500000 rows data frame.

Comment: @PhilippeRamirez  That's strange.  How many columns you were changing?

Comment: One at a time, with your first dplyr function

Comment: @PhilippeRamirez  I couldn't reproduce the problem.  Please check the update

Comment: Ok, the pb would be with the visualization. Applying the function on a small table will show me the full results (on RStudio) with correct capitalization. But a head(data) will return the original spellings. And similarly with a write.csv. What should I do to capture the results nicely?

Comment: @PhilippeRamirez  I don't use `RStudio`.  So I can't comment on it.

Comment: I found a way: assign the results to a new table. Thanks

Comment: @PhilippeRamirez  That is what I showed in `res1 <- ...`  If you need it to be in place, try `library(magrittr);data %<>%  mutate(surname = sub("(.)", "\\U\\1", surname, perl=TRUE))`  It will replace the values in the original 'data'.

Answer (score 9):

A little late to the party but you can use `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

example1 <- tibble(names = c("john" ,"Mary", "John", "mary"))

example1 %>%
mutate(names = str_to_title(names))

##  names
##  <chr>
## 1 John 
## 2 Mary 
## 3 John 
## 4 Mary
```

This will still work if you want all terms capitalized

```
example2 <- tibble(names = c("john james" ,"Mary carey", "John Jack", "mary Harry"))

example2 %>%
mutate(names = str_to_title(names))

##  names
##  <chr>
## 1 John James 
## 2 Mary Carey 
## 3 John Jack
## 4 Mary Harry
```

If you  only want the first term capitalized, `str_to_sentence()` will work

```
example2 %>%
mutate(names = str_to_sentence(names))

##  names
##  <chr>
## 1 John james 
## 2 Mary carey 
## 3 John jack
## 4 Mary harry
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a dedicated function for this that you can try:

```
R.utils::capitalize(data$surname)
```

If this needs to be implemented into a `dplyr` procedure, one could try the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(R.utils)
data %>% mutate(surname = capitalize(surname))
```

Comment: Thanks RHertel. Your solution seems to work also. My pb is that I cannot get the final product. As I reponded to Akrun above, applying the function on a small table will show me the full results (on RStudio) with correct capitalization. But a head(data) will return the original spellings. And similarly with a write.csv. What should I do to capture the results nicely?

Comment: I found a way: assign the results to a new table. Thanks